# <C-j> mapping not working in Vim when calling Vim from ZSH Vi mode

Tags: vim, zsh

When calling Vim from zsh via `vim`, `<C-j>` works perfectly and I am able to use it to select completions in the same manner as `<C-n>`.

When starting Vim from zsh's vi mode via the `v` key, I cannot get `<C-j>` to behave the same as `<C-n>`, whether I input the key-bind manually or place it in the config.

Additionally, when I invoke `edit-command-line` manually, `<C-j>` works.

Note: this issue does not arise when calling Vim in a similar manner in Bash's vi mode.

.vimrc with Vim 8.0

```
inoremap <expr> <C-j> "\<C-N>"
inoremap <expr> <C-k> "\<C-P>"
```

.zshrc with `zsh 5.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0)`

```
EDITOR="vim"
set -o vi
autoload -Uz edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bind key -M vicmd 'v' edit-command-line
```

EDIT: some further investigation reveals that when I start Vim through zsh's vi mode, `<C-v><C-j>` produces `^M`; however, when I start Vim normally, `<C-v><C-j>` produces `^@`.

Comment: AFAIK, the zsh has vi-mode (`set -o vi`) built in; you can *not* use an arbitrary external editor like vim for that. The value of the `EDITOR` variable is only used to select the startup value for `set -o`.

Comment: @Jens yeah, vim can't be used to edit the command line while in zsh's vi mode, but you can trigger `edit-command-line` via `v` in vi mode, which opens the current command line entry in your `$EDITOR`.